# Use Core Services Framework with IOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, core-services

I need use this framework with IOS 4.3 Scheme, How can i do this?
I want to create a gallery app, i´ve created the interface but i need download some pictures.

I´ve used WSStub(server in objective c) and WSJava(client in java).
I send picture code in Base 64, i receive this string decode and save in NSData but when i try to save in UIImage... i showed a error.

After solve this problem adding Uikit framework and changing scheme to IOS 4.3, Core Service framework is uncompatible.....

Comment: Please provide some more details. What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps you should edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this framework and mark as "Optional" (Xcode 4.2) "Weak Linking" prior versions.

And check for OS version in your code and do accordingly..